# pytest -3.2.2 duplicate test

Tags: python, pytest

test_set.py contains

```
 def test_a():
     pass

 def test_b():
     pass

 def test_a():
     pass 

 def test_a():
     pass
```

running pytest --keep-duplicates test.py run only one instance of test_a to show

```
 test::test_a   PASSED
 test::test_b   PASSED
```

how Can I run test.py to run test_a (thrice) ?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the documentation, the [`--keep-duplicates`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#keeping-duplicate-paths-specified-from-command-line) is useful to run tests if you have files with the same name in different directories.

The short answer is that it is not possible to do what you want.

---

A longer answer is that when a variable is defined multiple times in a file, the last definition overwrite all the previous ones. This is true for simple variable assigmen as well as for anything else.

For example, if you have a file `hitchhiker.py` with the following code:

```
a_variable = 42
[some code]
a_variable = 'towel'
```

and you import it, `a_variable` will have the value `'towel'`.

If you modify your test file in the following file:

```
def test_a():
    print('a1')

def test_b():
    print('b')

def test_a():
    print('a2')

def test_a():
    print('a3')
```

and then run it, you get:

```
-> py.test test_a.py -s -v
[...]
collected 2 items 

test_a.py::test_b b
PASSED
test_a.py::test_a a3
PASSED
```

As you can see the function last defined in the file is executed. If you move the first function at the end of the file, you will see that `a1` is printed.

Comment: Thanks. I thought each test was object and can be collected separately. using --keep-duplicates.

Comment: I think that ``py.test`` uses the python interpreter to load test files, so it cannot do what you hoped.