# run a test more than onces with pytest.main([])

Tags: pytest

I want to  run tests by calling pytest like this:

```
tests = ['path\testfile.py::test_init','path\testfile.py::test1','path\testfile.py::test2','path\testfile.py::test_deinit',
'path\testfile.py::test_init','path\testfile.py::test3','path\testfile.py::test4','path\testfile.py::test_deinit']

pytest.main(tests)
```

How many tests are defined within init and deinit is up to the tester to define in the testsfile.py(if necesary I can explain this logic), My question is: Pytest only runs  the test_init and test_deinit only once and for the second line on the command both are not runned, so current pytest output on the log is for example like this:

tests collected: 8

- test_init
- test1
- test2
- test_deinit
- test3
- test4

For test 3 and 4 the init and deinit where not runned. Is there a way I can influcence this?
This tests control some hardware so some init and deinit has to be made to prepare test preconditions.

The expected Result would be on the log for example:
tests collected: 8

- test_init
- test1
- test2
- test_deinit
- test_init
- test3
- test4
- test_deinit

This is how the test suite is defined currently in testfile.py:

```
child1={'name':'child1_suite_name',
'tests':[test1,tests2]}

child2={'name':'child2_suite_name',
'tests':[test3,tests4]}


testsuite={'name': 'test suite',
'setup':test_init, 'teardown':test_deinit, 
'tests' :[child1,child2]
}
```

The current framework does the unpacking and calling of the tests in the suite and the setup and teardown when the dictiory is passed.

I have tried with fixtures but that requires to put the test_init or test_deinit on the input parameters of the tests, I also tried setup_module(module) but this only runs before all the tests in a file and teardown_module(module) after the tests in the file where run, not in between.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: I found this answe wich is some how related to what I want to do, but in my case Im not redefining test_init and test_deinit, I just want to run them again at a specific order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387285/pytest-3-2-2-duplicate-test

Comment: Looks like you actually want fixtures for setup/teardown of your tests. You seem to be misusing other tests for this. Maybe you can explain why you want to do it this way.

Comment: I have been given the task to replace a testframe work (not pytest) that works this way. init and deinit are not tests, but have to be runned before and after a certain number of tests.

Comment: You mean you cannot change the test code to convert these to fixtures?

Comment: one requirement is that the two frameworks should be interchangable, Ill have a look at fixtures, thanks for the hin.

Comment: You could have fixtures that invoke those `init` and `deinit` functions coming from the custom framework to retain the interchangeability. Tests in pytest should have unique ids, all the duplicates collected will be just filtered out.

Comment: Thanks, I added more explanation to the post, on how the curret setup works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add fixtures to init and deinit on the file where they (testfile.py) where defined and used:

```
@pytest.fixture
def init():
    print("This is init_system")


@pytest.fixture
def deinit():
    #in old framework yield should be ignored in pytest it should be active
    yield
    print("this is deinit")
```

Since I could not add the fixtures in the test arguments due to framework compatibility I used this on conftest.py to add them to tests accordingly to the testsuite dictionary:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        #find before or after which test of testfile.py init or deinit should run and add fixture accordingly
        item.fixturenames.append('init')
        item.fixturenames.append('deinit')
```